# Issue downloading a complete website for offline use with HTTrack

Tags: httrack

I downloaded sonst.cc with HTTrack, but when viewing it offline there’s no content. Every single tab is empty.

When I open the index file, downloaded with HTTrack, in Safari the front page loads just fine with the background image, the menus... everything is perfect! Except when I click on any of the menus the tabs open up empty! No content at all!!! That said, it downloaded the whole site... html, css, js, images, ...and when I look at the code everything seems fine. It's all there!

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the [index file](http://ul.to/x74rqw80).

Why is that?

Is there any other app with which I could download the whole thing?

I’m losing my mind over here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `php` website, not static `html`, so you can't download it. You need source and server. You can save manualy one page at a time and correct links, if site is not so big, but still it's not going to be `clone`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really cheap way that should work.

This website seems to require authentication to enter, firstly make sure you take care of that. Here's one way. Open the site in Chrome, login, right click and save as Webpage Complete to some folder in your computer. Then install Python 2 from https://python.org/download (should be a button that says Python 2 and then version numbers after decimal point). Go to the folder where your files are and open cmd there. Type `path to python installation/python2.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer`. IF port 8000 is closed then put the port number after a space, then go to localhost:8000 or whatever port number is there. It should work.